# AWS Glue weird memory usage with python 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using spark in AWS Glue to process data from my S3 bucket and write the result to a Redshift Cluster. Until today, I always use the following libraries version:

Python 2.7
Glue 0.9
Spark 2.2

Because Python 2 will be deprecated in January, I started to convert all of my scripts in Python 3.6. In order to do that I also changed the version of Glue and Spark, respectively to 1.0 and 2.4.

After the upgrade, I started to issue many out of memory errors. All of my Job Runs failed for the same error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.resolveChoice.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 38 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 38.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 474, ip-172-75-5-103.eu-central-1.compute.internal, executor 119): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 119 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.8 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.

Here are the metrics showed by Cloudwatch:

[image: Python 2.7 Memory Usage]

Python 2.7 Memory Usage

[image: Python 3.6 Memory Usage]

Python 3.6 Memory Usage

I would like to enlighten, that both of the Jobs were processing the same data and the script is identical except for the python version used. Here is a piece of code that I used:

```
sc = SparkContext()
glue_context = GlueContext(sc)
glue_context.setConf('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
spark = glue_context.spark_session
job = Job(glue_context)

s3_parts = CustomRetriever(bucket=params['bucket'],
                               location_prefix=params['location_prefix'],
                               ymdh_from=params['from'],
                               ymdh_to=params['to'])

try:
    job.init(params['JOB_NAME'], params)

    for part in s3_parts:
        part_path = part.get_path()

        sources = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame \
            .from_options(connection_type="s3",
                          connection_options={'paths': part, 'recurse': True, 'groupFiles': 'inPartition'},
                          format="json", transformation_ctx="source")

        resolution_choice = ResolveChoice.apply(frame=sources, choice="cast:double")

        # Spark transformations
except:
    logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
    raise
finally:
    job.commit()
```

CustomRetriever is a simple custom library that retrieve the s3 paths of the data to process. The Job in python 3 always failed at the Resolve Choice function.

Anyone else faced the same issued with Python 3?

Comment: same problem here, found a solution?